# what`s the scope of mockito verify?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, verify

Assuming message is mocked,
in the following case - the last `verify` remembers to 2 before him?
So the number that supposed to be in `times` is `times(3)`?

```
   when(message.hasMessages()).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(message.hasMessages());
    assertTrue(message.hasMessages());
   verify(message, times(2)).hasMessages();
    assertTrue(message.hasMessages());
    verify(message, times(1)).hasMessages();
```

Comment: Why not have a look at the Mockito documentation? For example [JavaDoc for the Mockito class](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.4.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification) where it states **_Once created, a mock will remember all interactions._** Still, your question re-enforces that point...

Answer (score 1):

Mockito doesn't reset the invocation counter. `verify` counts *all* method invocations of a mock.

So `verify(message, times(3)).hasMessages();` would be correct, because `hasMessages()` was invoked exactly 3 times.